# How do I stop seeing reactions on my feed in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

In LinkedIn, most people's reactions bring useless content to my feed and force me to stop following them. Be it unfunny Facebook-like memes, be it useless "click X if you agree, click Y if you disagree", be it completely fake HR stories, I don't wanna see it. If the person didn't find it interesting enough to SHARE, I don't want to see it.

Is it possible to see only original content and shared content on my feed? If so, how?

---

In response to this mod comment:

> show what you have tried, share what you found from this site and from the official resources for LinkedIn end users , i.e. [Linkedin Help](https://linkedin.com/help/), and why it didn't meet your needs.

Searching for `inurl:linkedin.com/help/ intitle:reactions` on Google gave me the following results:

1. [Use LinkedIn Reactions](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a528190/use-linkedin-reactions?lang=en)
2. [Using LinkedIn Reactions in Group Conversations](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a549002/using-linkedin-reactions-in-group-conversations?lang=en)
3. [Use LinkedIn Reactions](https://www.linkedin.com/help/recruiter/answer/a528190)
4. [Use LinkedIn Reactions](https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/a528190)
5. [Using LinkedIn Reactions in Group Conversations](https://www.linkedin.com/help/sales-navigator/answer/a549002/like-and-unlike---group-conversations?lang=en)

They are not helpful because they are targeted for people that doesn't even know that Reactions exist. It does not mentions the possibility of configuring how Reactions show in the Feed.

Searching for `inurl:linkedin.com/help/ intitle:feed "reactions"` on Google gave me the following results:

1. [Best Practices to Customize What you see on Your LinkedIn Feed](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a528031/best-practices-to-customize-what-you-see-on-your-linkedin-feed?lang=en)
2. [Best Practices to Customize What you see on Your LinkedIn Feed](https://www.linkedin.com/help/recruiter/answer/a528031)
3. [Best Practices to Customize What you see on Your LinkedIn Feed](https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/a528031)

They are not helpful because they suggest only muting and unfollowing people to customize what I see on my feed. But that's already what I'm doing. I'd like to have a more fine-grained configuration, like, following people's publications, but not their reactions.

**Examples of useless content:**

Reaction vote:
[image: Reaction vote.]

Probably fake quote:
[image: Fake quote.]

People unhappy with their currently job, criticising their employer:
[image: Clown]

Facebook-like unfunny memes:
[image: Unfunny meme]

Fake HR stories:
[image: Fake HR story]

Begging a job position ('share to help me find a work position'):
[image: 'share to help me find a work position']

Off-topic content, aka SPAM (non-professional content):
[image: Religious SPAM]

Comment: Rather than adding more and more examples, show what you have tried, share what you found from this site and from the official resources for LinkedIn end users , i.e.https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin?lang=en, and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: @Rubén at your request, I edited the question description, adding why none of the results for `inurl:linkedin.com/help/ intitle:reactions` is helpful.

Comment: I contacted [LinkedIn Support](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/contact) and got this answer: "_Unfortunately, the functionality you're referring to is currently not yet supported by LinkedIn. I hope you understand._ [...] _I would suggest you submit this under the [LinkedIn Feedback report](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/feedback) instead for your future convenience. The more voices being heard to certain reports, improvements, or suggestions, the faster Linkedin will look into such issues._"

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Your question has been reopened. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OFFICIAL LINKEDIN REPLY:**

I contacted [LinkedIn Support](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/contact) and got this answer:

> Unfortunately, the functionality you're referring to is currently not yet supported by LinkedIn. I hope you understand. [...] I would suggest you submit this under the [LinkedIn Feedback report](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/feedback) instead for your future convenience. The more voices being heard to certain reports, improvements, or suggestions, the faster Linkedin will look into such issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you think that "reactions" are a type of message that can be blocked. That is incorrect.

What you are showing in the question body are just images asking LinkedIn users to use the "reactions" feature.

To learn about the LinkedIn feed read [LinkedIn Feed - Overview](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a523360).

To tell LinkedIn that you don't want to see a certain type of content in the LinkedIn feed, follow the instructions at [Hide content in your feed](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a523209).

To be more specific, when LinkedIn shows something in your feed because one of your contacts "reacted" to it, that content will be framed (included in a box). The name of your contact that "reacted" is shown at the top of that frame and to the right, there is a meatball menu (horizontal three-dot menu):
[image: Meatball Menu]

Click the menu, then select "I don't want to see this"
[image: Meatball Menu Options]

Then you will be asked to tell LinkedIn why you don't want to see that
[image: Don't want to see this]

If the reasons shown don't meet your needs, send your feedback directly to LinkedIn.

Reference

- [Use LinkedIn Reactions](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a528190)

Comment: "What you are showing in the question body are just images asking LinkedId users to use the 'reactions' feature." They are examples of the content that I don't want to see on my feed, and that only appeared there through my contact's reactions. This content was not posted nor shared by my contacts, they just reacted to it. And that is my problem: content not relevant enough to be posted nor shared is showing up on my feed and I don't want that.

Comment: Follow the instructions of "Hide content in your feed"

Comment: Answer updated to included images.

Comment: "Hide content in your feed" did no difference in the months I had been using it, so I gave up on it. You hide one irrelevant post today and 10 others appear tomorrow. I tried hiding all "share to help me find a job", but they still kept resurfacing. LinkedIn does not deduces that I don't want to see reactions. At best, it deduces that I don't want to see one specific post.

Comment: Send your feedback to LinkedIn.

Comment: Thank you. I did not remember that [LinkedIn is contactable](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/contact), unlike other social networking websites. I have opened a support case there and will update here as soon as I get an answer.

Comment: I contacted [LinkedIn Support](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/contact) and got this answer: "_Unfortunately, the functionality you're referring to is currently not yet supported by LinkedIn. I hope you understand._ [...] _I would suggest you submit this under the [LinkedIn Feedback report](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/feedback) instead for your future convenience. The more voices being heard to certain reports, improvements, or suggestions, the faster Linkedin will look into such issues._"